# How to optimize vendor.bundle.js file size and startup loading using webpack and angular2/4

Tags: angular, webpack-production

I have vendor.bundle.js of 6MB size. I am using webpack configuration, how to reduce the size of vendor.bundle.js to optimize the load performance. I have achieved the performance for rest of file only my vendor.bundle.js is taking time to load apprx 7 to 8sec. Does anyone can help on this. Is there a way to skip vendor.bundle.js on load.

Comment: is this production bundling (--prod) or development ?

Comment: production --prod. How to gzip the vendor.bundle.js ?

Comment: indeed that's too much for production build. If your application is indeed very large, try splitting it across multiple modules and use lazy loading to load them. Can you post your packages.config file too ?

Comment: I am already using lazy loading.

Comment: If you are using RxJs, have you tried replacing 'rxjs' to exact correct imports. eg: use import { Observables } from 'rxjs/Observables' instead of import 'rxjs'

Comment: yes. I do have correct imports for specific use of rxjs like observable map etc. but still i will again verify it once and optimize my code. what other than matters for size ?

Comment: I have checked that import statements are correct. No use of direct rxjs. But still vendor bundle size remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reduced the size of vendor.bundle as two npm libraries included the data within the js itself so size was taking up 6mb so removed the library. Now the size is 890KB

Comment: Do you know which libraries were doing this?  And if you removed the libraries how did you replace the functionality they provided?

Comment: Those two libraries were for country code and cities zipcode library as i am not onto my system i dont remember specially lib names but in place of them I have used the regex pattern for cities zip codes as i am limiting app usage country specific whereas for country codes also i have build up constant json that contains all the country codes.

Answer (score 2):

According to me the straight forward way to reduce loading time of Angular Application is :

Post Build :

1. Use UglifyJS to eleminate white spaces in your main.bundle.js and vendor.bundle.js. Size reduction is around 50%.
2. Every server (Tomcat,Nginx) has capabilities of sending compressed versions of your JS/HTML/JPEG/etc to the client using `gzip` compression. Enable it for your server.

Using these two techniques my overall download size reduced significantly from `8 MB` to `650 KB`.